# asp.net web api long action names

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have long action names like this:

- GetBestSellerProducts
- GetBestSellerProductsThisYear
- GetBestSellerProductsThisYearInCity
- GetGeaturedProductsWeek

But the names are not useful for api URI.

- `http://localhost/api/product/GetBestSellerProductsThisYear`
- `http://localhost/api/product/GetBestSellerProductsThisYearInCity/225412`

Is there any practical way to separate small and readable URI.

- `http://localhost/api/product/statistics/bestseller/thisyear`

Answer (score 1):

```
[ActionName("Profile")]
public ActionResult MyProfile()
```

You can use ActionName attribute for this